# How to pass NSError to method

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a method which take the parameter

```
(void(^)(NSError*))errorCall;
```

I need to pass errorCall value

```
-(void)message{

example = [[Example alloc]init]
[example opertationError:void(^)(NSError*))errorCall ]; 
}
```

for the below line

```
[example opertationError:void(^)(NSError*))errorCall];
```

i need to pass some custom error call which in type of  `void(^)(NSError*))errorCall`

Please any one let me know how to pass this kind of error value to the method.

@All

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
void(^aBlock)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) {
    ...
};
[self errorValue:aBlock];
```

Comment: Thanks for replay What will be inside Error block?

Comment: whatever you want to write, your program flow, logic, manipulations etc